# Change value of PropertyTagImageDescription

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I'm trying to solve the problem of changing the value PropertyTagImageDescription (0x010E) for the Bitmap object. To add a description for the file. Searching the related topics, and has not found the solution. My use:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(fileName));
var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My comment");
PropertyItem propItem = image.GetPropertyItem(Convert.ToInt32(0x010E));
propItem.Len = data.Length;
propItem.Value = data;
image.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
```

But there is an error : "In GDI + error occurred generic."

Help me understand! What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get to your error I haven't found a image that has the 0x010E property set. But I have build a little console application that works:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string imageLocation = @"C:\Users\Jens\Desktop\image.jpg";
        string newImageLocation = @"C:\Users\Jens\Desktop\newImage.jpg";

        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534415(VS.85).aspx
        Int32 ImageDescription = 0x010E;

        // get file stream and create Image
        using (var fs = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(fs, false, false))
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My comment");

            // get a property from the image file and use it as container  
            var propItem = img.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault();

            // set the values that u like to add
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.aspx
            propItem.Type = 2;
            propItem.Id = ImageDescription;
            propItem.Len = data.Length;
            propItem.Value = data;

            // add property to Image and save it to the system
            img.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
            img.Save(newImageLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need  change file comment! not EXIF